# Visual Studio: unable to remove directory, access to the path is denied

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, google-drive

При каждой новой сборке проекта Visual Studio выдаёт:

> Unable to remove directory "bin\Debug\app.publish". Access to the
> path 'bin\Debug\app.publish' is denied.

Знаю точно, что это происходит из-за синхронизации гугл-диска с новыми файлами - удаление bin\Debug\app.publish\ вручную решает проблему и проект можно собрать. Подошло бы убрать несколько подпапок из синхронизируемых, но судя по https://support.google.com/drive/thread/123477997/how-can-i-select-only-specific-folders-to-sync-with-the-latest-version-of-google-drive-desktop?hl=en, этой фичи уже нет (с оффлайн подпапкой, видимо, тоже). Что можно ещё попробовать сделать? Для папки снимал стандартное ограничение на только для чтения к файлам, безрезультатно.

Comment: попробуйте запустить VS от админа

Comment: @tym32167, не помогает

Comment: а зачем вообще синхронизировать `bin\Debug`? нельзя выключить синзронизацию для этой папки?

Comment: @tym32167, подпапки нельзя с какой-то обновы в гугл-диске убирать из синхры

Comment: ну если гора не идет к Магомеду, то можно попробовать [попросить VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022) в дебаг режиме собирать сборку в другом месте, которое не трекается?

Comment: @tym32167, да, это подойдёт. Единственный минус это то, что перед каждым первым запуском, нужно будет выбирать директорию, потому что эта настройка синхронизируется (хотя у меня на другом компе показывалась отличная директория от той, на которую менял - в итоге всё равно не собралось пока не выставил вручную). Но это уже лучше, спасибо

Comment: Ну, если вообще говорить, я бы не стал гугл драйвом синхронизировать. Есть же всякие гитхабы, через них и история вся сохраняется, и опыт работы с гитом получите.

Comment: Да, ты прав, буду пробовать